# Style shinyWidget::dropdownButton in shinydashboard::box header

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard, adminlte

**Background**

I am trying to place a `shinyWidget::dropdownButton` in the header of a `shinydashboard::box`. The button should have the look and feel of the button created when using a collapsible box (`box(..., collapsible = TRUE)`.

With the help of some JavaScript I was able to move the dropdown, which seemed to me the easier approach rather than constructing all the `HTML` myself.

The code below does what I want to do, however I am struggling with the `css`, because the elements in the dropdown are partly white on white (which makes sense I guess because they are (grand) children of class `.box-tools`)

**What I want**

I want that all controls in the dropdown look like as if I put the dropdown in the body of the box:

[image: Dropdown in the Body]

**Goal:** *Dropdown in the body*

[image: Dropdown in the Header]

**Current Situation:** *Dropdown in the header*

**Questions**

How can I achieve this? Which `css` rules do I have to use, to make sure that any kind of control looks like as if in the body of the box? Could I achieve the same behaviour even easier? (For instance by wrapping all my controls in the dropdown in another element)? I do know my basics in `css` but here I feel a bit at loss which rules I need to consider to get to the desired result.

---

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)

makeDropDown <- function(i) {
  dropdownButton(
    h3("Heading"),
    selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "Select:", LETTERS),
    downloadButton(paste0("down", i), "Load"),
    circle = FALSE,
    icon = icon("cog")
  )
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    box(solidHeader = TRUE,
        status = "info",
        title = "Box",
        div(
          makeDropDown(1),
          class = "box-tools pull-right",
          id = "moveme"
        ),
        makeDropDown(2)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  runjs("$('.box-header').append($('#moveme').detach())")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, some CSS rules are overwritten, you can use some inline CSS with `!important` to control appearance :

```
makeDropDown <- function(i) {
  dropdownButton(
    tags$div(
      style = "color: black !important;", # for text
      h3("Heading"),
      selectInput(paste0("sel", i), "Select:", LETTERS),
      downloadButton(
        outputId = paste0("down", i), label = "Load", 
        style = "background-color: #f4f4f4 !important; color: #444 !important; border: 1px solid #ddd !important;" # for button
      )
    ),
    circle = FALSE,
    icon = icon("cog")
  )
}
```

Otherwise, maybe @DivadNojnarg have a better solution in [`shinydashboardPlus`](https://github.com/DivadNojnarg/shinydashboardPlus), I'll ask him !

Comment: could you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233401/in-r-how-to-create-multilevel-radiogroupbuttons-as-each-level-depends-choicena?noredirect=1#comment104681894_59233401