# in R, how to create multilevel radioGroupButtons, as each level depends choiceNames depend on the previous level input?

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, shinywidgets

I am trying to create shinyapp in which the first `radioGroupButtons` will automatically update the second level of `radioGroupButtons` and then the 3rd level, eventually each level will filter the `datatable`

used code

```
library(shiny)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)

hotdrinks<-list("tea","green tea") 
juices<-list("orange","mango") 
energydrinks<-list("powerhorse","redbull") 
drinks<-list("hotdrinks"=hotdrinks,"juices"=juices,"energydrinks"=energydrinks) 

biscuits<-list("loacker","tuc") 
choc<-list("aftereight","lindt") 
gum<-list("trident","clortes") 
sweets<-list("gum"=gum,"biscuits"=biscuits,"choc"=choc)

all_products<-list("sweets"=sweets,"drinks"=drinks)
mt<-melt(all_products)
mt2<-mt%>%mutate("Price"=c(23,34,23,23,54,32,45,23,12,56,76,43),
             "Quantity"=c(10,20,26,22,51,52,45,23,12,56,76,43))

t1<-mt2[,c(4,3,1,5,6)]
t1
colnames(t1)<-c("CAT","PN","SP","Quantity","Price")

t2<-list(unique(t1$CAT))
t2

all <- list("drinks"=drinks, "sweets"=sweets)
```

app.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)


 ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("TEST"),
            mainPanel(
              fluidRow(
                column( width = 9,  align = "center",
                  radioGroupButtons(inputId = "item",
                    label = "",  status = "success",
                    size = "lg",  direction = "horizontal", justified = FALSE,
                    width = "100%",individual = TRUE,
                    checkIcon = list(
                      "yes" = icon("check"),
                      "yes" = icon("check")
                    ), 
                    choiceNames = as.list(unique(t1$CAT)),
                    choiceValues = as.list(1:length(unique(t1$CAT)))
                  )
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                column( width = 9,  align = "center",
                        radioGroupButtons(inputId = "item2",
                                          label = "",  status = "success",
                                          size = "lg",  direction = "horizontal", justified = FALSE,
                                          width = "100%",individual = TRUE,
                                          checkIcon = list(
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check")
                                          ), 
                                          choiceNames = NULL,
                                          choiceValues = NULL
                 ))),
              fluidRow(
                column( width = 9,  align = "center",
                        radioGroupButtons(inputId = "item3",
                                          label = "",  status = "success",
                                          size = "lg",  direction = "horizontal", justified = FALSE,
                                          width = "100%",individual = TRUE,
                                          checkIcon = list(
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check"),
                                            "yes" = icon("check")
                                          ), 
                                          choiceNames = NULL,
                                          choiceValues = NULL
                        ))),

              fluidRow(
                column( width = 9,
                wellPanel(dataTableOutput("out"))
              ))))

 server <- function(input, output) {
   observeEvent({
     print(input$item)
         oi<-t1%>%filter(CAT==input$item)%>%select(PN)
         updateRadioGroupButtons(session, inputId="item2", 
                        choiceNames =unique(oi),
                        choiceValues = as.list(1:length(unique(t1$PN))))

             ox<-t1%>%filter(CAT==input$item2)%>%select(SP)
             updateRadioGroupButtons(session, inputId="item3", 
                        choiceNames =unique(ox),
                        choiceValues = as.list(1:length(unique(t1$SP))))

             })
   out_tbl <- reactive({
     x <- ox[,c("Quantity","Price")]
     })
   output$out <- renderDataTable({
     out_tbl()
     },options = list(pageLength = 5)
   )
   }

 shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

the desired result is like this [image]

I used [this as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563989/create-center-navigation-bar-in-shiny-with-symbols?noredirect=1&lq=1)

UPDATED CODE----------------

```
hotdrinks<-list("tea","green tea") 
juices<-list("orange","mango") 
energydrinks<-list("powerhorse","redbull") 
drinks<-list("hotdrinks"=hotdrinks,"juices"=juices,"energydrinks"=energydrinks) 

biscuits<-list("loacker","tuc") 
choc<-list("aftereight","lindt") 
gum<-list("trident","clortes") 
sweets<-list("gum"=gum,"biscuits"=biscuits,"choc"=choc)

all_products<-list("sweets"=sweets,"drinks"=drinks)
mt<-melt(all_products)
mt2<-mt%>%mutate("Price"=c(23,34,23,23,54,32,45,23,12,56,76,43),
                 "Quantity"=c(10,20,26,22,51,52,45,23,12,56,76,43))

t1<-mt2[,c(4,3,1,5,6)]
t1
colnames(t1)<-c("CAT","PN","SP","Quantity","Price")
mtx<-t1
df<-mtx

library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# make a data frame for choices



buttons_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("buttons"))
}

buttons_server <- function(input, output, session, button_names, button_status) {

  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns

    radioGroupButtons(
      inputId = ns("level"),
      label = "",
      status = button_status(),
      size = "lg",
      direction = "horizontal",
      justified = TRUE,
      width = "100%",
      individual = TRUE,
      checkIcon =  setNames(
        object = lapply(button_names(), function(x)
          icon("check")),
        nm = rep("yes", length(button_names()))
      ),
      choiceNames = button_names(),
      choiceValues = button_names()
    )
  })

  selected <- reactive({ 
    input$level
  })

  return(selected) 
}

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(fluidRow(
  column(
    width =9,
    align = "center",
    buttons_ui(id = "level1"),
    buttons_ui(id = "level2"),
    buttons_ui(id = "level3"),
    tags$hr(),
    dataTableOutput("tbl")
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected1 <-
    callModule(module = buttons_server,
               id = "level1",
               button_names = reactive({ unique(mtx$CAT) }), 
               button_status = reactive({ "success"}) )

  selected2 <-
    callModule(
      module = buttons_server,
      id = "level2",
      button_names = reactive({ mtx %>% filter(CAT == selected1() ) %>% pull(PN) %>% unique }),
      button_status = reactive({ "primary" })
    )

  selected3 <-
    callModule(
      module = buttons_server,
      id = "level3",
      button_names = reactive({ mtx %>% filter(CAT == selected1(),PN==selected2() )%>%pull(SP) %>% unique }),
      button_status = reactive({ "warning" })
    )
  # add more calls to the module server as necessary

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    df %>% filter(CAT == req(selected1()), PN == req(selected2()),SP == req(selected3()))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: *"each level ... depends on the previous"*: you need `uiOutput` and `renderUI` for dynamic generation of shiny/HTML objects.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

Comment: @r2evans i tried a lot could you please send me a working code

Comment: Not now, I cannot. I hope somebody else will fill the gap.

Comment: @r2evans never mind , thank you for your response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can update choices dynamically in `observeEvents`, here's a demo:

```
# Data
dat <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
  L3 = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
  L2 = c("gum", "gum", "biscuits", "biscuits", "choc", "choc",
         "hotdrinks", "hotdrinks", "juices", "juices", "energydrinks",
         "energydrinks"),
  L1 = c("sweets", "sweets", "sweets", "sweets", "sweets", "sweets",
         "drinks", "drinks", "drinks", "drinks", "drinks", "drinks"),
  Price = c(23, 34, 23, 23, 54, 32, 45, 23, 12, 56, 76, 43),
  Quantity = c(10, 20, 26, 22, 51, 52, 45, 23, 12, 56, 76, 43),
  value = c("trident", "clortes", "loacker", "tuc",
            "aftereight", "lindt", "tea", "green tea", "orange",
            "mango", "powerhorse", "redbull")
)


# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)


# App
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$br(),

  # Custom CSS
  tags$style(
    ".btn-group {padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;}",
    "#l1 .btn {background-color: #5b9bd5; color: #FFF;}",
    "#l2 .btn {background-color: #ed7d31; color: #FFF;}",
    "#value .btn {background-color: #ffd966; color: #FFF;}"
  ),


  tags$br(),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      offset = 4,
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "l1",
        label = NULL,
        choices = unique(dat$L1),
        justified = TRUE,
        checkIcon = list(
          "yes" = icon("check")
        ), 
        individual = TRUE
      ),
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "l2",
        label = NULL,
        choices = unique(dat$L2),
        justified = TRUE,
        checkIcon = list(
          "yes" = icon("check")
        ), 
        individual = TRUE
      ),
      radioGroupButtons(
        inputId = "value",
        label = NULL,
        choices = unique(dat$value),
        justified = TRUE,
        checkIcon = list(
          "yes" = icon("check")
        ), 
        individual = TRUE
      ),
      tags$br(),
      DT::DTOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$l1, {
    updateRadioGroupButtons(
      session = session,
      inputId = "l2",
      choices = dat %>% 
        filter(L1 == input$l1) %>%
        pull(L2) %>%
        unique,
      checkIcon = list(
        "yes" = icon("check")
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$l2, {
    updateRadioGroupButtons(
      session = session,
      inputId = "value",
      choices = dat %>% 
        filter(L1 == input$l1, L2 == input$l2) %>%
        pull(value) %>%
        unique,
      checkIcon = list(
        "yes" = icon("check")
      )
    )
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    dat %>% 
      filter(L1 == input$l1, 
             L2 == input$l2,
             value == input$value)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Result lokk like:

[image]

Comment: mille merci @Victorp :)

Answer (score 1):

As @r2evans suggests one way to get this behavior is with `uiOutput` and `renderUI`. Here is a minimal app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# make a data frame for choices

level1 <- LETTERS[1:3]
level2 <- 1:5

df <- expand.grid(level1, level2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(Var2=paste(Var1, Var2)) %>% 
  arrange(Var1)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3, "some space"),
      column(
        width = 9,
        align = "center",
        radioGroupButtons(
          inputId = "level1",
          label = "",
          status = "success",
          size = "lg",
          direction = "horizontal",
          justified = FALSE,
          width = "100%",
          individual = TRUE,
          checkIcon =  setNames(
            object = lapply(unique(df$Var1), function(x) icon("check")),
            nm = rep("yes", length(unique(df$Var1)))),
          choiceNames = unique(df$Var1),
          choiceValues = unique(df$Var1) 
        ),
        uiOutput("level2"),
        tags$hr(),
        dataTableOutput("tbl")
      )
    )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # render the second level of buttons
  make_level <- reactive({

    df2 <- filter(df, Var1 %in% input$level1)

    radioGroupButtons(
      inputId = "level2",
      label = "",
      status = "primary",
      size = "lg",
      direction = "horizontal",
      justified = FALSE,
      width = "100%",
      individual = TRUE,
      checkIcon =  setNames(
        object = lapply(unique(df2$Var2), function(x) icon("check")),
        nm = rep("yes", length(unique(df2$Var2)))),
      choiceNames = as.list(unique(df2$Var2)),
      choiceValues = as.list(unique(df2$Var2))
    )
  })

  output$level2 <- renderUI({
    make_level()
  })

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    df %>% filter(Var1 == req(input$level1), Var2 == req(input$level2))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Another way to achieve this is with shiny modules. Here is an example of how that might look. This code is more concise, because the radio buttons are defined once as part of the module and then the module is called as necessary. Because dependency between levels, we still need `renderUI` in the module.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

# make a data frame for choices

level1 <- LETTERS[1:3]
level2 <- 1:5

df <- expand.grid(level1, level2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(Var2 = paste(Var1, Var2)) %>%
  arrange(Var1)

buttons_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("buttons"))
}

buttons_server <- function(input, output, session, button_names, button_status) {

  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns

    radioGroupButtons(
      inputId = ns("level"),
      label = "",
      status = button_status(),
      size = "lg",
      direction = "horizontal",
      justified = FALSE,
      width = "100%",
      individual = TRUE,
      checkIcon =  setNames(
        object = lapply(button_names(), function(x)
          icon("check")),
        nm = rep("yes", length(button_names()))
      ),
      choiceNames = button_names(),
      choiceValues = button_names()
    )
  })

  selected <- reactive({ 
    input$level
    })

  return(selected)
}

ui <- fluidPage(mainPanel(fluidRow(
  column(width = 3, "some space"),
  column(
    width = 9,
    align = "center",
    buttons_ui(id = "level1"),
    buttons_ui(id = "level2"),
    # buttons_ui(id = "level3"),
    # buttons_ui(id = "level4"),
    # and so on..
    tags$hr(),
    dataTableOutput("tbl")
  )
)))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  selected1 <-
    callModule(module = buttons_server,
               id = "level1",
               button_names = reactive({ unique(df$Var1) }), 
               button_status = reactive({ "success"}) )

  selected2 <-
    callModule(
      module = buttons_server,
      id = "level2",
      button_names = reactive({ df %>% filter(Var1 == selected1() ) %>% pull(Var2) %>% unique }),
      button_status = reactive({ "primary" })
    )

  # add more calls to the module server as necessary

  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    df %>% filter(Var1 == req(selected1()), Var2 == req(selected2()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: can't thank you enough , one more question, as you see in my data they are 3 levels so when i tried to create      ````button_names = reactive({ df %>% filter(Var1 == selected1(),Var2 == selected2() ) %>% pull(Var3) %>% unique }),``` the values not responding

Comment: it doesn't show actual names just it shows 1,2,3,4,,,

Comment: What was the error? Might be that the new column is a factor? But hard to tell without the code.

Comment: Thanks again for your fast response , no error message , level1 and level2 show real names but level 3 shows 1,2,3,,,,

Comment: yes, as I suspected, `SP` is a `factor` (check with `str(mtx)`). Convert `SP` to `character` when you make `mtx` to see names (not levels). Or, when you call the module for the third time, use `as.character` after `pull`.