# Create Dummy Variable if NA 1 else -1

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I want to create a dummy where all cells that include NA become 1 and all other cells -1.
I tried to different things both not resulting in my desired outcome.

1) This leads to only NA Values.

```
Cox.Reg$FirstTask <- ifelse(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth == NA, 1, -1)
```

2) This leads to only the -1 values being shown in the new column.

```
Cox.Reg$FirstTask <- ifelse(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth == "NA", 1, -1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is a real `NA`, then we can use `is.na` to detect the `NA` elements, which would return `TRUE` for all `NA` and `FALSE` for others as a logical vector, which can be used in `ifelse` to change the values

```
ifelse(is.na(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth), 1, -1)
```

Or another option is to create a numeric index and change the values accordingly

```
c(-1, 1)[is.na(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth) + 1]
```

Comment: I have another question, now i want to create a dummy variable if the cell value is 1 to 7, then the dummy variable  should be 1 else -1. I tried to solve it like this but it does not work.. Thank you in advance! Cox.Reg$FirstTask <- if((Cox.Reg$dayofmonth_created >=1 && Cox.Reg$dayofmonth_created <=7) 1, -1)

Comment: @Amy INn that case you can either use `%in%` or `>=/<=` but  with `&` and not `&&` i..e. `ifelse(Cox.Reg$dayofmonth_created >=1 &Cox.Reg$dayofmonth_created <=7, 1, -1)`

Comment: One last question, what would i do if i have variables that need a baseline. eg. they can be for example when i want to know which day of the week, so i would need the output to be binary yet still show me on which day it was created

Comment: @Amy  In that case, it would be better to have it as logical `is.na(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth)` because you can wrap with `which(is.na(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth))` to find the position always

Comment: Hi @akrun can you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233401/in-r-how-to-create-multilevel-radiogroupbuttons-as-each-level-depends-choicena?noredirect=1#comment104681894_59233401

Comment: Yet another way: `2*is.na(Cox.Reg$active_task_avg_depth) - 1`.